# Query to output the execution time of a stored procedure from a database other than Master DB

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get report from one of my databases other than sys.
I know that I can see the average execution time of system stored procedures using this query

```sql
SELECT  plan_handle, total_worker_time / execution_count as AVG_EXEC_TIME
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
ORDER BY  AVG_EXEC_TIME DESC
```

But how can I find the same average execution time of a user defined database.

Comment: I see plenty of user-created objects when I run that query, so I don't know what you mean here

Comment: Specifically if i want to check the execution time of a stored procedure which is present in the user defined database.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: I have tried this SELECT o.name,s.total_elapsed_time,s.min_elapsed_time,s.max_elapsed_time, s.last_execution_time, s.type_desc  FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats s INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id WHERE DB_NAME(s.database_ID) = '' -dbname AND o.name LIKE ('%%') --obj name, But i get only one row in the result. But i need n-rows with each execution times